# accepted answer indication

Tags: feature-request, design

In accepting an answer for a question, I just ended up pressing the "accept" button several times in a row as I didn't detect an obvious change in color. Admittedly I was doing other things at the time on other web pages, but I think this would be easier to use if the button would change to a new color more different from the previous.

Here's the marking as it stands:
[image]

Here's an example of marking that will be obvious even to old people like me:

[image]

Comment: Seems to be closely related to: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1117/the-color-difference-between-the-answered-checkmark-and-the-unanswered-one-i